# Rails - How to pass arrays of ids as params for hidden field?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, methods, request, delete-row

In rails 4 application, there is a list of data along with checkbox(multiple) option. I want to delete some selected data, for normal `delete` method I tried 1000 rows at a time and it returns `414 Request-URI Too Large`. Because all ids are passing in URL as same as `get` method.

I have tried to fix this by using form submit by passing ids as hidden field but ids are blank. Because ids should get through checkbox.

Is there any way to fix this issue in direct request by passing ids as params? Before that we need to ask confirmation `Are you sure?` too.

How can we get selected checkbox ids and assign to params here?

Please help me, somehow I should be able to delete 1000 rows at a time.

Comment: Why you not tried to making it with POST request ? Because if you use javascript or any related hack it always will take time to process 1000 records.

Comment: "somehow I should be able to delete 1000 rows at a time". This should never be done with a GET request. GET should always be idempotent and not create, delete or alter resources. Use DELETE.

Comment: Even POST method returns same error as GET/DELETE method returns `414 Request-URI Too Large`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the length limitations of the query field of a url, you can use the POST method.

Since this would not be consistent with the REST paradigm, you may wish to include a hidden field to pass the "_method" attribute with value "delete", which is Rails way to implement the DELETE verb on top of an http POST request.

Of course, you need to make sure the route is properly specified to route this request to the appropriate rack endpoint.